# Handling multiple accounts in Android app

Tags: android

I would like to build an application that caters for multiple accounts (eg. home, work) and account types (e.g. ISP, VoIP, Mobile). Essentially, I would like to get the user to create the accounts they want and then have all the accounts listed on the start page grouped by type. For example:

ISP:
 - Home
 - Work

Mobile:
 - Mum
 - Dad

When you click on the account, it would take you to another screen where I do a bunch of calcs and display the results.

I currently do this via multiple apps but am looking at consolidating into the one app. I am just not sure where to start or how I go about achieving this? The way the Contacts app works is a good example of what I am wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have an Account table. Have a foreign key to the Account table in all your other tables. When querying, filter based on the current Account.

Comment: So use SQL to handle the accounts?

Comment: Well, your data presumably goes somewhere. If you don't want to use SQLite, that's fine -- for example, use individual flat files per account or something.